# Video camera stream does not capture continuously

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, video-capture

I have a program that reads from video camera, and finds the maximum color intensity of all the frames. I noticed that there is a dashed line effect when I streak a laser pointer across the camera viewing area.

I think this is because the fps of the camera is less than the shutter speed of the camera. or that the waitkey function prevents the camera to read during that period.

Is there a way to remove this effect so that if I streak a laser pointer across the camera view it leaves a continuous line?

EDIT: I also need the results in real time if that is possible.

here is the simplified code below:

```
while 1:
      ret, view = vid.read()
      outputImg = processImage(view)
      cv2.waitkey(1)
      imshow(outputImg)
```

[image]

Comment: What's the fps of the camera?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think my fps is process bound instead of camera bound. My process is taking a frame every .07 seconds so ~15fps

Answer (score 0):

You should try to first save the video and then process it later.

```
while 1:
      ret, view = vid.read()
      outputImg = processImage(view)
      cv2.waitkey(1)
      imshow(outputImg)
```

Your code captures a frame and then processes it using your `processImage` function and then waits in `cv2.waitkey(1)` and then displays the processed frame, and finally, again reads the next frame. So there is a time lapse between reading of the two frames. You can save it like this:

```
while 1:
    ret, frame = vid.read()                 
    out.write(frame)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Sorry if this is elementary but what is out in your example? I also forgot to mention that I need to output the image in real-time as well.

Answer (score 0):

While [shiva's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5468701/shiva) suggestion will probably improve your results, it will still be unpredictable, and the behaviour will greatly depend on the capabilities of the camera and your ability to control it. I would expect the gaps to be there.

Instead, I would make an attempt at correcting this:

- Find the endpoints of each streak in a frame.
- Find the two adjacent endpoints in adjacent frames.
- Draw artificial laser line connecting those two points. (Perhaps by using a sample taken from both ends and interpolating between them)

---

If for some reason you can't interpolate, but still need to be able to do the processing in near-realtime, consider putting the image acquisition into a separate thread. Set this thread to high priority, to minimise the gaps between the frames.

This thread will repeatedly:

- Acquire frame from camera.
- Insert the frame into a synchronized queue.

Then, create a processing thread (this could be your main thread as well), which will take the frames from the synchronized queue, and do whatever processing is necessary.

---

To achieve the best results, you should use a camera that is able to run in "freerun" mode, where the camera automatically triggers itself, and sends a stream of data to the computer to process.

This might not be possible to do directly with OpenCV and a regular webcam. Some lower-end industrial camera, either a GigEVision or USB3 model might be more appropriate. (AVT Manta, Basler Scout, etc.) You may be able to find some good deals on EBay if the cost is out of your price range.

You would most likely need to use a special API to control the camera and acquire the frames, but the rest of the processing would be done using OpenCV.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion however I can't really interpolate for reasons in later usage of this program.

Comment: In that case put the video acquisition into a dedicated high-priority thread. Feed them to a queue that you will process asynchronously in another thread.

Comment: Or, depending on what your requirements and the intent of this project are, you could go for a camera that can run in "free-run" mode. That means the camera automatically triggers itself, and continuously sends frames to the computer. Probably some GigEVision (or USB3) industrial camera would be good for that. Of course, those are not exactly cheap, but you can find good deals on EBay.

Comment: hmm. I will do some research on multi-threading. Thank you for your help.